# Dagger 2 and interface implementations

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, mvp, dagger-2

I've got a simple Dagger 2 test-setup, based on http://konmik.github.io/snorkeling-with-dagger-2.html.
It injects a PreferenceLogger which outputs all the preferences. In the injected class, I can @Inject more classes.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Inject PreferencesLogger logger;
    @Inject MainPresenter presenter;

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MyApplication.getComponent().inject(this);
    presenter.doStuff();
        logger.log(this);
    }
}


public class PreferencesLogger {

    @Inject OkHttpClient client;
    @Inject public PreferencesLogger() {}

    public void log(Contect context) {
    // this.client is available
    }
}
```

When I run this, logger is set, and inside PreferencesLogger.log the OkHttpClient is correctly set.
So this example works as expected. 
Now I'm trying to get a MVP structure in place.
There's a MainPresenter interface with an implementation. In the MainActivity I set an:

```
@Inject MainPresenter presenter;
```

so I could switch this MainPresenter with an alternative (debug or test) implementation. Ofcourse, now I need a Module to specify what implementation I want to use.

```
public interface MainPresenter {
    void doStuff();
}

public class MainPresenterImpl implements MainPresenter {

    @Inject OkHttpClient client;

    public MainPresenterImpl() {}

    @Override public void doStuff() {
    // this.client is not available    
    }
}


@Module public class MainActivityModule {
    @Provides MainPresenter provideMainPresenter() {
        return new MainPresenterImpl();
    }
}
```

A problem now occurs that the OkHttpClient isn't injected anymore. Ofcourse I could alter the Module to accept a parameter OkHttpClient, but I don't think this is the suggested way to do it. Is there a reason why the MainPresenterImpl doesn't Inject correctly?

Comment: I asked a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555285/dagger2-injecting-implementation-classes-with-component

Comment: take a look at this article and sample project which might help:
https://medium.com/@m_mirhoseini/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21#.6y9ze7e55

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike with constructor injection, the `@Inject` annotated fields of dependencies constructed in `@Provides` methods can't be automatically injected. Being able to inject fields requires a component that provides the type of the field in its modules, and in the provider methods themselves, such an implementation is not available.

When the `presenter` field is injected in `MainActivity`, all that happens is the provider method is called and `presenter` is set to its return value. In your example, the no-args constructor does no initialization, and neither does the provider method, so no initialization takes place.

The provider method does however have access to instances of other types provided in the module via its parameters. I think using parameters in the provider method is in fact the suggested (even the only) way to "inject" the dependencies of the provided type, because it explicitly indicates them as dependencies within the module, which allows Dagger to throw an error at compile-time if they can't be satisfied.

The reason it doesn't currently throw an error is because `MainPresenterImpl` *could* get its `OkHttpClient` dependency satisfied  if `MainPresenterImpl` and not `MainPresenter` was somewhere a target for injection. Dagger can't make a members-injection method for the interface type, because as an interface, it can't have injectable fields, and it won't automatically inject the fields of the implementing type, because it's just supplying whatever the provider method returns.

Answer (score 5):

You could be able to inject your `MainPresenterImpl` using constructor injection.

```
/* unscoped */
public class MainPresenterImpl implements MainPresenter {

    @Inject 
    OkHttpClient client;

    @Inject
    public MainPresenterImpl() {
    }

    @Override public void doStuff() {
       // this.client is now available! :)
    }
}


@Module 
public class AppModule {
    private MyApplication application;

    public AppModule(MyApplication application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    /* unscoped */ 
    public MyApplication application() {
        return application;
    }
}

@Module 
public abstract class MainActivityModule {
    @Binds public abstract MainPresenter mainPresenter(MainPresenterImpl mainPresenterImpl);
}
```